# Some rows of Order by column is null. How to make Order by column optional on that situation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a prob in following  Select query.

```
select * 
from ".$table2." a,purpose_details b 
where  b.purpose_code=a.purpose and purpose_code in(1,4,6,7,10)  
  and ((fromdt<='$frmdate'and todt>='$frmdate') 
         or (fromdt<='$frmdate' and todt='1111-11-11')) 
  and  substr(a.appno,4,1)!=6  
order by purpose_priority,
         cast(substr(a.case_no,12,4) as int) ,cast(substr(a.case_no,4,1) as int),
         cast(substr(a.case_no,5,7) as int),cast(substr(a.appno,12,4) as int) ,
         cast(substr(a.appno,4,1) as int),cast(substr(a.appno,5,7) as int)";
```

the problem is the rows in the table2 may or may not have value of appno. (ie) appno value may be NULL for some of rows.

Due to appno is one among in the order by column this particular code retuns invalid input error.

Finally What i want is the **select query arrange the columns by appno only when the appno value is not null**.

Note: The order by clause for the rest of the columns should be applied on both situations.

Pls help me to sort it out. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Order by can definitly handle null values but substr cannot.
You should replace your

```
Substr (col, ...
```

With

```
Case when col is null then null else substr (col, ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Sir. But the problem still persisting. But when i remove the cast() from the order by clause it solves the problem.